# How does PHP access sessions directory which has root owner?

Tags: php, apache, session, cron, directory-permissions

I am curious about

> Why cron is used to cleanup session files in Ubuntu?

I have researched over it and found two links saying that

> "for the security purpose sessions are kept under root permissions.
> Because of that PHP Garbage Collector is not able to clean up the
> expired session files. For cleaning such files php has cron job which
> runs after every 30 minutes."

[1. Why does Debian clean php sessions with a cron job instead of using php's built-in garbage collector?](https://serverfault.com/questions/511609/why-does-debian-clean-php-sessions-with-a-cron-job-instead-of-using-phps-built)

[2. Debian Bug report logs - #267720](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=267720)

Apache has www-data user, so I think PHP module is also running for www-data user(Not sure about this).

> If this is the condition, How can PHP access the session directory
> which has root owner to create/read session files?
>
> Does PHP run with root permissions even though apache has www-data
> user? If PHP runs with root permissions, then how GC failed to read
> session files from sessions directory which has root owner.
>
> Or Does GC run with www-data user and PHP run with root user?

**Addition to that:**

I have checked the user and owner of created file in the /var/lib/php/sessions and it shows www-data:www-data for the created session file.

The permissions for /var/lib/php/sessions are **drwx-wx-wt**

**i.e. it has sticky bit "t"**

> **Sticky Bit:**
>
> The sticky bit is a permission bit that protects the files
> within a directory. If the directory has the sticky bit set, a file
> can be deleted only by the owner of the file, the owner of the
> directory, or by root. This special permission prevents a user from
> deleting other users' files.
> [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-4883/secfile-69/index.html#secfile-66)

**Now, the question is under which user GC is running? If it is running under www-data, why it is not able to delete session files?**